# 2A Brushed motor driver

Tags: power, driver, dc-motor

I need to power 2 brushed dc motors with 2A each and 3 to 6V, one direction(no bidirectional or break). To the enable the rpi 3.3V pwm, and standard pins(breadboard), not those micro pins. I know the l298 is an option. Are there better efficent options ? May be mosfet ? Thanks.

Comment: The L298N may be underpowered for 2 amp continuous.  If you mean 4 amps (2 amps per motor) it is certainly underpowered.  If all you want to do is switch the motor on/off a MOSFET is likely to be a much better choice.  This is the wrong stack exchange for this question (nothing to do with the Raspberry Pi).  Perhaps try electronics stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NPN transitor and use the GPIO control to turn the motor on/off. There are several posts on this [here](http://www.davidhunt.ie/howto-switching-onoff-a-dc-motor-with-a-raspberry-pi/) and [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41173/how-to-switch-on-off-a-circuit-using-gpio).

If you do not want to deal with the wiring, you can use one of the H-bridge motor driver HAT's available for the Pi like [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2348).

Comment: I'd like 1 or 2 transistor but I couldn't find one that match 2A and the voltage... I want something more essential than the hat.

Comment: You can use a Darlington transistor like this https://www.adafruit.com/product/976

Comment: No, neither an NPN transistor nor especially not a darlington is  a viable option for this - there's just too much loss in a low-voltage, high current application.  An N channel MOSFET is what should be used.

Comment: Some mosfet could be a good idea. I like IC drivers overcurrent protection but those boards are expensive: 15$ for a 2$ IC... I'll post an update soon. Should I parallel the outputs of 2 1A mosfet or what ?